# iTheme Security always lockout my account

Tags: security

I develop websites with Wordpress and for security reasons I always install iTheme Security and Wordfence.

In the past months, with 7/10 websites my username is always locked out from iTheme Security 'cause brute-force attack and password guessing.

How can I solve this annoying issue?